# Jenkins shared library update properties file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline, properties-file

I'm creating a shared library with utilities for the pipelines. The problem is that I don't know how to update a properties file. In the pipeline utility steps there is a readProperties, the idea is to readProperties modify a few and then save the results in the same file. Any idea or utility that I can use?

Comment: Do you have some properties in hand and needs to be updated to a property file?

Comment: I already have a properties file with the content, for example:
VARIABLE1.prop1=value1
VARIABLE1.prop2=value2

And I want to update only the "value2"